# LibGDX game closes on Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having this confusing problem with my LibGDX game for Android. It works fine on my good old Samsung Galaxy SIII mini, but on the newer Grand Prime it crashes (or closes) spontaneously without any error messages.
The game typically closes during the assets loading either at the very beginning of the game or when I load more assets. I am using LibGDX AssetManager for Textures and Sounds and I try to also unload the unneeded assets midgame. I tried optimizing the code and added a lot of unloading of unnecessary assets and I resized all the .png files to a minimum and the situation is still roughly the same. I don't very much understand what's happening, especially since it works flawlessly on some devices, but on others it just doesn't.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this error has kept me awake for the past two nights with no real solutions.

Thanks!

This is the last piece of code that I get from my app before the app closes:

```
08-17 11:00:27.738 531-539/myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 42.912ms
08-17 11:00:34.528 531-545/myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.441ms
08-17 11:00:35.808 531-770/myapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 11:00:36.238 531-539/myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.010ms
08-17 11:00:36.388 531-545/myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3398(597KB) AllocSpace objects, 36(1981KB) LOS objects, 21% free, 9MB/12MB, paused 864us total 115.093ms
08-17 11:00:37.508 531-545/myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.111ms
08-17 11:00:37.518 531-545/myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 673(146KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(2MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 10MB/12MB, paused 8.256ms total 39.363ms
08-17 11:00:37.658 531-545/myapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 195(28KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(343KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 9MB/12MB, paused 1.584ms total 133.245ms
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with AssetManager.update() method. Still no idea why.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your log filtered? I've never seen anything crash on Android without some kind of error in the log.

Comment: It was filtered to only my application.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the Grand prime any more, since it was my friend's phone, so I can not elaborate any more on the issue. On the "bright side", my application now also spontaneously closes on my S III mini, for which I've created a separate thread.

Comment: And sorry for a late reply, I just had limited phone internet connection and loading anything was problematic.